# C# vs C++ security

Tags: c#, c++, security

I am writing an app with a friend, that knows C#.
I want to code that in the most hard-to-decompile code.
What are the security differences between C# and C++? (In terms of viewing the code in a compiled executable)

Comment: "In terms of viewing the code in a compiled executable", C#.NET won't help you to hide it.

Comment: I don't understand this strange fascination with obfuscating binaries.
For what? There's a ton of open source projects with comments and all abandoned
by their authors, and no one wants to pick them up.
Not that they're bad projects, for instance Gnome Do is good, just no one is that interested.
Believe me, when someone's interested enough to decompile a binary - nothing will stop them.
But in all probability no one will even try.
And if your doing this for security through obscurity, there are a lot better ways to go.

Comment: First: this question is not about actual code and is too vague for StackOverflow; it should be closed. Second: if you don't want users to be able to decompile your super-secret awesome code that no one else could come up with, **don't give the binaries to your customers in the first place**. Keep the code on your server and provide a service. Then all you have to protect against is server attacks. Decompilation of any language is easy, and **plenty of people can read machine code**. It's not like it's a secret how machine code works.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty short and simple to explain, assuming release builds without debug information:

`C/C++:` You'll get assembler code and that's it. Based on the knowledge of the one decompiling, this can be rather easy to understand or simply impossible. There's no general answer here, as this also depends on complexity of the code itself (i.e. "what is it actually doing?").

`C#:` As for all .NET languages decompiling is a lot easier, because the resulting binary essentially only contains immediate language code you can decompile into readable code. This won't necessarily result in the same code you've had the first place (variable names might be lost, there are no comments and optimizations might obscure some code), but in the end it's far easier to understand and modify.

There are code obfuscators available making reading decompiled .NET code harder to understand, but in general you should always assume there's always someone who'll be able to understand and reverse engineer your code, even if your code is just a black box.

Comment: there is also pro security suite like SafeNet for example to Scramble/crypt native binary exe and DLL.

Comment: Wouldn't really recommend using those: Some antivirus programs might flag their code/activity as suspicious (trying to hide code), especially when you're not able to build a huge reputation fast (e.g. big/popular game or something like that to be whitelisted by users accepting your program). If you worry about piracy, try to make fair pricing, offering something people like to pay for. If we're talking about some kind of server/client thingy, double check everything server side and don't just trust the client.

Comment: And if i compile it in mono?

Comment: There's no difference. Essentially Mono is just an alternative runtime providing the same (or mostly the same) classes. Mono (and Microsoft's .NET as well) here acts pretty much just like the Java Runtime Environment.